# Run a python code using CLI without pem file from an EC2 using AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have made and automation to process a particular file and save it. I have an EC2 machine. I want others to use this code to upload the file and download the output from my EC2 instance, without having any access to the code or the machine.

Is this possible from Amazon CLI for other users?

Comment: I think that you might want to create a web API here.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the file is processed? How long does it take to process the file? Are you using any complex libraries? The reason I ask is that it might be worth moving your code to an AWS Lambda function. Then, users could upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket, which could automatically trigger a Lambda function, which could then process the file and save it back to S3. So, users simply upload, then download and you don't even need to run an EC2 instance all the time.

Comment: Are you performing any sort of authentication on your users, or the ability to use this processing service?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It is a little complicated as it calls another program on a production server and gets the output. Files used to be small and in my program, I do not have much complex processing. Also what I'm looking for some basic authentication for users.

Comment: You should consider the complete flow for users and try to make it as simple as possible for them to use. A good way would be to allow them to access a web page served by the instance, where they can authenticate and upload files. They could then return later to view a list of files they can download. This would be much simpler than having them login to a remote computer and upload/download files.